# Error.captureStackTrace when trying to run test Neo4J file with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I'm trying to run Neo4j's test file with Node, I followed the instructions here: https://neo4j.com/developer/

In my app project I installed both `neo4j-driver` and `neo4j` (via yarn) and created the test neo4j.js file.

Then run the neo4j community edition server.

```
// npm install --save neo4j
var neo4j = require('neo4j');
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://neo4j:<password>@localhost:7474');

var insertQuery = 
  "UNWIND {pairs} as pair \
   MERGE (p1:Person {name:pair[0]}) \
   MERGE (p2:Person {name:pair[1]}) \
   MERGE (p1)-[:KNOWS]-(p2)";

var foafQuery = 
 "MATCH (person:Person)-[:KNOWS]-(friend)-[:KNOWS]-(foaf) \
  WHERE person.name = {name} \
   AND NOT (person)-[:KNOWS]-(foaf) \
  RETURN foaf.name AS name";

var commonFriendsQuery =
"MATCH (user:Person)-[:KNOWS]-(friend)-[:KNOWS]-(foaf:Person) \
 WHERE user.name = {name1} AND foaf.name = {name2} \
 RETURN friend.name AS friend";

var connectingPathsQuery =
"MATCH path = shortestPath((p1:Person)-[:KNOWS*..6]-(p2:Person)) \
 WHERE p1.name = {name1} AND p2.name = {name2} \
 RETURN [n IN nodes(path) | n.name] as names";

var data = [["Jim","Mike"],["Jim","Billy"],["Anna","Jim"],
            ["Anna","Mike"],["Sally","Anna"],["Joe","Sally"],
            ["Joe","Bob"],["Bob","Sally"]];

function query(query, params, column, cb) {
    function callback(err, results) {
        if (err || !results) throw err;
        if (!column) cb(results)
        else results.forEach(function(row) { cb(row[column]) });
    };
    db.cypher({ query: query, params: params}, callback);
}

query(insertQuery, {pairs: data}, null, function () {
    query(foafQuery, {name: "Joe"},"name", console.log); 
    query(commonFriendsQuery, {name1: "Joe", name2:"Sally"},"friend",console.log);
    query(connectingPathsQuery, {name1: "Joe", name2:"Billy"}, "names", 
          function(res) { console.log(res)});
});
```

When I go to the dir and run `node neo4j.js` I get the following error:

[image]

I also tried changing line 3 to: `var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j/issues/211) with `node-neo4j` running on Node.js v7. Please note that the package you are using is not the official driver, which is in the npm registry as [neo4j-driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver). The

Comment: What is the official driver? It's the same name? `neo4j-driver`

Comment: The names are a bit confusing. The name of the official driver is [neo4j-driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver). The one you referred to in your example ([neo4j](https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j)) is another package.